# Haskell - Maybe and Recursion

Tags: haskell, option-type

I want to take a string and turn into into a list of `Direction`. For example, `"UDDUD"` should return `[U,D,D,U,D]`, whereas any string that does not contain a `U` or `D` returns `Nothing` (e.g. "UDYD" returns `Nothing`).

```
data Direction = U | D
    deriving (Show, Eq)
-- where U is Up and D is Down

findDirection :: [Char] -> Maybe [Direction]
findDirection [] = Nothing
findDirection ['U'] = Just [U]
findDirection ['D'] = Just [D]
findDirection (x:xs)
    | x == 'U' = Just (U : findDirection xs)
    | x == 'D' = Just (D : findDirection xs)
    | otherwise = Nothing
```

I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[Direction]’
                with actual type ‘Maybe [Direction]’
    In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘findDirection xs’
    In the first argument of ‘Just’, namely
      ‘(U : findDirection xs)’

Test_findDirection.hs:8:32:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[Direction]’
                with actual type ‘Maybe [Direction]’
    In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘findDirection xs’
    In the first argument of ‘Just’, namely
      ‘(D : findDirection xs)’
```

As I understand it, `Just (D : findDirection xs)` and `Just (U : findDirection xs)` are of type `[Direction]`? Why is this the case? What am I doing wrong, here?

Comment: `U : findirection xs` (and `D : findDirection xs`) is ill-typed: you cannot cons a `Direction` to a `Maybe [Direction]`. Besides, you write: *[...] any string that does not contain a `U` or `D` returns `Nothing` (e.g. `"UDYD"` returns `Nothing`).* Are you not contradicting yourself, here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `Just (D : findDirection xs)` and `Just (U : findDirection xs)` are of type [Direction]? Why is this the case? What am I doing wrong, here?

No, `Just (D : findDirection xs)` is actually ill-typed. Let's dissect this error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[Direction]’
                with actual type ‘Maybe [Direction]’
```

We're using `Maybe [Direction]` at a point where we should actually use `[Direction]`.

```
In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘findDirection xs’
```

Aha. We're using `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` wrong. After all, `findDirection` will return a `Maybe [Direction]`, not a `[Direction]`. We need something like this:

```
consOnMaybe :: a -> Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a]
consOnMaybe _ Nothing   = Nothing
consOnMaybe x (Just xs) = Just (x : xs)
```

Now your function can be written as

```
findDirection (x:xs)
    | x == 'U' = consOnMaybe U (findDirection xs)
    | x == 'D' = consOnMaybe D (findDirection xs)
    | otherwise = Nothing
```

Alternatively, we  could have used `consOnMaybe x = fmap (x:)`. As an additional bonus, here is a variant that uses pre-defined functions and no explicit recursion (exercise: understand how it works)

```
findDirection :: [Char] -> Maybe [Direction]
findDirection [] = Nothing
findDirection xs = traverse toDirection xs

toDirection :: Char -> Maybe Direction
toDirection 'U' = Just U
toDirection 'D' = Just D
toDirection  _  = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  data Direction = U | D
    deriving (Show, Eq)

  findDirection :: String -> Maybe [Direction]
  findDirection [] = Nothing
  findDirection dirs = sequence $ findDirection' dirs
    where
      findDirection' :: String -> [Maybe Direction]
      findDirection' (x:xs) =
        let x' = toDirection x in
          x' : case x' of
                Just _ -> findDirection' xs
                _ -> []
      findDirection' _ = []

      toDirection :: Char -> Maybe Direction
      toDirection 'U' = Just U
      toDirection 'D' = Just D
      toDirection _ = Nothing

------------------------ OR ------------------------

findDirection :: String -> Maybe [Direction]
  findDirection [] = Nothing
  findDirection dirs = traverse toDirection dirs
    where
      toDirection :: Char -> Maybe Direction
      toDirection 'U' = Just U
      toDirection 'D' = Just D
      toDirection _ = Nothing

> findDirection "UDDUD"
< Just [U,D,D,U,D]

> findDirection "UDYD"
< Nothing
```